# Remove HTML from NSString but keep maths symbols

Tags: ios, objective-c, regex, cocoa

I need to strip out all HTML formatting from an NSString but I need to retain any < (less than) symbols when relevant to the string's contents.

For example:

```
<p>Dogs:  For dogs <10KGs use 1:1000 solution (1000 µg/ml) diluted to 5-10 ml.</p>
```

I need this to read:

```
Dogs:  For dogs <10KGs use 1:1000 solution (1000 µg/ml) diluted to 5-10 ml.
```

So far the common approach is to use something along the lines of:

```
  NSRange r;
  NSString *s = [[self copy] autorelease];
  while ((r = [s rangeOfString:@"<[^>]+>" options:NSRegularExpressionSearch]).location != NSNotFound)
  s = [s stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:r withString:@""];
  return s;
```

But this method results in:

> Dogs: For dogs

The first HTML tag is stripped correctly but the <10KGs is assumed to be the opening of an HTML tag with p> closing is it and so removing that whole section.

How can I handle < when it is used for content and not tags?

Comment: HTML containing `<` that isn't part of a tag is badly formed (they should be encoded as `&lt;`). Therefore you are trying to parse something with errors in it. This is no going to be easy to be reliable. For example if the input contains `<em` is that a tag missing its closing angle bracket (`>`) or a less than operator?

Comment: Unfortunately, I have no control over the formatting of the incoming HTML. I am fairly sure, however, that it will contain only <xx>, </xx> and <xx /> tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code to,

```
NSRange r;
NSString *s = [[self copy] autorelease];
while ((r = [s rangeOfString:@"<[^<>]+>" options:NSRegularExpressionSearch]).location != NSNotFound)
s = [s stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:r withString:@""];
return s;
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/xM2sY2/4)

This will strip off the paragraph tags in the above example. `[^<>]+` matches any character but not of `<` or `>` , one or more times.

Comment: Ah, this seems to do the job perfectly, I had obviously not been paying attention to the regex in my code.  Thanks.